# How to execute a hidden Process that requires user interaction without blocking?

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, command

Please don’t mark as duplicate before read.
After looking a lot of google search I found a lot of code. All the codes are okay but my problem is little bit more.
Suppose, I can execute `‘dir’` command using this below code which gives me perfect output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     var str=ExecuteCommand("/c dir");
     //var str=ExecuteCommand("/c chkdsk C: /f/r/x");
     MessageBox.Show(str);
    }


static string ExecuteCommand(string cmd)
        {
            Process proc = new  Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();
            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            return output;
        }
```

But, when I run this command `“/c chkdsk C: /f/r/x”` then no output comes because it waits for user input(y/n). I want to view output and send y or n from my C# code not by cmd console window.

Comment: WinForms application? What kind of UI element do you use (want to use) to show the console output?

Comment: @elgonzo: winform or console, I need just code. It could be a messabebox or console window.

Comment: You need to redirect standard input https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Subscribe to the [`Process.OutputDataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event to get the console output of the process you started (i.e. "cmd /c ..."). Note that you need to call [Process.BeginOutputReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx) on your process object (before calling Start()), otherwise the event will not fire. With regard to input, see the MSDN link in Will's comment above...

Comment: @elgonzo: I also tried OutputDataReceived. It doesn't solve my problem. It waits for user input. I mean same problem I describe.  'process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler2);'